# Do TYPO3 have a user configuration cache?

Tags: caching, typo3

I have been watching a strange issue that is making me think that TYPO3 has a sort of user configuration cache and don't know how to clean it.

The website has some users and some groups of users. There are some extensions to manage records on tables.

Some of the fields of those extensions are of type "group" to reference files.

The strange thing is that the old users in the same group don't see the upload button in those fields, but when create new users in the same group they do see the button.

There is no difference between the configuration of the old and new users.

What might be happening?

**More Info:**

They are BE users and the problem is in the Web->List view.

No special modules and no disabled_controls in the TCA for those fields.

It is also interesting that if I duplicate an old user, the duplicated one is not able to see the buttons, either.

**Images**

This is how the old users see the fields:

[image: Old user]

And, this is how the new users see the field:

[image]

Comment: It is very hard to guess with the given explanation. Are you talking of the TYPO3 backend and backend users? There is no such cache in TYPO3 itself, however there could be some, if the extension that you use comes with an own backend module that does such magic (however I would not expect that).

Comment: Thank you @StephenKing for your reply. I have added more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect, that there are Options in TSUser Config or in user settings are set.

Have a look in TSConfig of that Users and Usergroups:

```
setup.default.edit_docModuleUpload = 0
setup.override.edit_docModuleUpload = 0
```

Perhaps it is set in the user settings:

[image]

Comment: You're absolutely right! It was a misconfiguration. I had hidden the field using `edit_docModuleUpload.disabled = 1`, but I forgot to override the value. So, new users got the value by default, but when save the preferences they change the value without notice.